How do I wait for an HttpClient subscription to wrap up before returning the data in Angular 18
I'm working with Angular 18 and I'm trying to query data from an API so I can store it inside my component. I'm able to successfully console.log the API data stored in my object with both my component and the service that I'm using to retrieve the data. However, whenever I try to console.log its key or any of its values on their own, undefined shows up in the console. In addition, using Object.keys with the object returns an empty array.
I found a similar stackoverflow post here, and while it says that the issue stems from the opened object in the console not accurately depicting its current value, I'm not sure how to fix the issue. I tried looking into ways to delay the data I receive from my query's subscription, so that I can store the data into the variable before the rest of the code executes. Sadly though, the only stuff I found was what I had already been trying. Making it so that the object require the this keyword to be used didn't help either. I don't want to use async/await if I can help it because I don't want to have to deal with returning Promises, but I can if there is no other way.
tldr: How do I wait for an HttpClient subscription to wrap up before returning the data from the API its querying?
api.service.ts
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  private collection: Collection = { cards: {} };

  queryApi(query: string): Observable<Data> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Data>(`https://api.scryfall.com/${query}`);
  }

  retrieveCard(name: string, set?: string): Cards {
    let card: Cards = {}

    this.queryApi(`cards/named?exact=${name}${typeof set != undefined ? `&set=${set}` : ""}`)
    .subscribe((json) => {
      card[json["id"]] = {
        name: json["name"],
        qty: 1,
        set: json["set"],
        imageURL: json["image_uris"]["png"]
      }
    });

    return card;
  }
}

add-cards.component.ts
export class AddCardsComponent {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}
  private tempCollection: Collection = { cards: {} };
  name: string = "";
  set: string = "";

  addTempCard(): void {
    const card: Cards = this.apiService.retrieveCard(this.name.toLowerCase(), this.set?.toLowerCase());
    console.log(card) // returns key and values
    console.log(Object.keys(card)[0]) // returns undefined

    this.name = "";
    this.set = "";
  }
}


Why doesn't the service expose Observable<Cards>?

The code inside the subscribe is asynchronous (waits for the API), but the code below it is synchronous (does not wait for the API). So you need to move the code below the subscribe into the subscribe, so that it executes after the API call is made. In your service, the return happens before the API completes this is the root cause of the issue.

Subscribe to the API on the component instead of on the service.
  retrieveCard(name: string, set?: string): Observable<Cards> {
    let card: Cards = {}

    return this.queryApi(`cards/named?exact=${name}${typeof set != undefined ? `&set=${set}` : ""}`)
    .pipe(map((json) => {
      card[json["id"]] = {
        name: json["name"],
        qty: 1,
        set: json["set"],
        imageURL: json["image_uris"]["png"]
      }
      return card; // <- notice!
    })
  );

  }
  

Then get the data on the component using subscribe, this will give you the exact result always.
export class AddCardsComponent {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}
  private tempCollection: Collection = { cards: {} };
  name: string = "";
  set: string = "";

  addTempCard(): void {
    this.apiService.retrieveCard(this.name.toLowerCase(), this.set?.toLowerCase()).subscribe((card: Cards) => {
      console.log(card);
      console.log(Object.keys(card)[0]);
      this.name = "";
      this.set = "";
    });
  }
}


Thank you for your quick response! For the retrieveCard() function's return value, it says that it is returning Observable instead of Observable but you gave me a great leaping off point, thanks!

@bascott my mistake, updated my answer!

It works, thanks again! I'll keep map in mind for future reference, I'm still learning about observables so this was a huge help.
